# Azure Storage Container roles

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Using service principals, I am trying to define two roles in my Azure Resource Group, one for the moderator:

```
az role assignment create --assignee <moderator app id> --role "Storage Blob Data Owner" --scope /subscriptions/<mysub>/resourceGroups/<myresourcegroup>
```

and one for the reader:

```
az role assignment create --assignee <readerapp id> --role "Storage Blob Data Reader" --scope /subscriptions/<mysub>/resourceGroups/<myresourcegroup>
```

The moderator can upload files to the container using:

```
azcopy copy <local path> "https://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>" --recursive=true
```

But when reader tries to get the content from the container wtih:

```
azcopy copy "https://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>" "<local path>" --recursive=true --overwrite ifSourceNewer
```

...the command fails with

```
failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, C:/Users/VssAdministrator/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.15.0/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
```

When I go into the portal and add the 'Storage Blob Reader' role to the container (as opposed to the resource group), the reader role is able to `azcopy` the contents of the container.

How do I add the role on container level from azure-cli, and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add the role on the container level from azure-cli, and why is it necessary?

To assign a **`storage blob data reader role`** to the container level you can use the below command:

**Command:**

```
az role assignment create --assignee <readerapp id> --role "Storage Blob Data Reader" --scope /subscriptions/<mysub>/resourceGroups/<myresourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container-name
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now I can able to get the content using the Azcopy command.

**Portal:**

In my container, I have some files.

[image]

First I login with the app credentials and I used with below command:

```
azcopy copy "https://youraccountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/*" "C:\Users\xx\xxx\input" --recursive=true
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Files:**
[image]

**Update:**

I got the same error when the reader app did not assign "**`storage blob data reader"`** role to my resource group level.

[image]

Once I assigned the storage blob data reader role to my reader app at the resource group level I was able to read the content from azure blob storage.

[image]

[image]

It worked successfully.

[image]

Make sure you log in with the correct application ID with the role.

Comment: “ The reason you need to add the role at the container level is that role assignment at the resource group level only allows authority to control the storage account and its resources, not the data within the storage account” - if this were the case, then how come upload (which is a data operation) worked in OP. There also the data management role applied at resource group level?

Comment: You are right about how to assign access rights at container level, but I would still like to know why it is necessary for reading while not for writing.

Comment: Check the updated answer and thanks @GauravMantri correcting me.